# Samsung Galaxy S6 Lite Tablet Pen: Palm Rejection in Android

Tags: tablet, stylus

I recently bought the Samsung Galaxy S6 Lite Tablet (Android). It has an S Pen included which works great and I get palm rejection with the in built Samsung app and also in Squid.

But when I use other popular apps such as Adobe pdf viewer, or zoom or Evernote the palm rejection does not seem to work.

Any idea if there's a fix for this?

Further more, the S Pen does not need to be charged (unlike say the Apple pencil); just curious how the active palm rejection etc. works if the pen is indeed passive and not active?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if they have any software incorporated that can do the palm detection.

However, you can use an hand glove (buy one or make a DIY from an old sock) to prevent your palm to be detected as input.

Hope that this can help you somehow.