# Pen with palm rejection support

Tags: applications, tablet, notes

My pen(or my tablet(?)) doesn't support palm rejection. What can I do to make it usable? Is there a way to "simulate" palm rejection? Any tricks that I can try?

This is the pen: https://www.amazon.it/Hommie-Universale-Protettiva-Ricaricabile-Smartphones/dp/B08G82VPBK/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8

This is the tablet: https://www.amazon.it/Lenovo-pollici-Qualcomm-Snapdragon-Android/dp/B07WY88LT3

What can I do to make it usable? Is there a way to "simulate" palm rejection? Any tricks that I can try?

Comment: Probably related? [Samsung Galaxy S6 Lite Tablet Pen: Palm Rejection in Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/231126/44325)

Comment: @AndrewT. nope :( I've altready tried with a glove